# Java Edition for Java Server Applications?

Tags: java, jvm

What is the preferred (Best Performing) Edition for Java server applications? Would I go with the Java Micro Edition, Standard Edition, Enterprise Edition, Java FX, or?

Right now I am leaning towards Java Micro because surly if it's the most light weight it'll have the best server performance?

I do not plan on adding a GUI, and probably never will.

I know this question might sound as an opinion based question, but it really isn't. I'm just looking for what editions will perform the best for such an application.

Comment: JavaFX is a GUI library which has nothing to do with what you describe. Choosing between the various options is a matter of what features you will need and use. Performance will be similar for a given feature.

Comment: The "edition" does not indicate performance, but the API's guaranteed to be provided by the JVM.  The micro edition have a lot less than the enterprise.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Surely if the API is bigger there will be more RAM required?

Comment: @Binero More software takes more disk space.  Java only loads the classes you use, so it doesn't have to use more memory.

Comment: It depends. What is your intended use for "such an application"?  Is it just running essentially as a batch processing daemon or service?  Are there external clients calling it (and how many?)? Are you looking at fastest straight-line performance, or overall throughput for a concurrent workload? Do you need to distribute it across thousands of devices, or only running on a single big server in a data centre? (but JavaFX is out anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server applications you will need [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) (Enterprise Edition).

As someone stated in comments of this answer you can run a server application even on Java Standard Edition, it depends on what the server application will do, and on what the requirements of the applications is ...

If you don't need any of the additional features of Java EE, run it on Java SE, and start the VM with the server option in this way :

```
java -server com.myapplication.main
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to understand what these 'editions' really are.

Standard Edition is basic Java. It means a normal JVM, and the normal class libraries.

Enterprise Edition is the Standard Edition plus a huge amount of libraries and frameworks aimed at helping build certain kinds of server applications. Most of those libraries and frameworks can also be used in Standard Edition. The main point of Enterprise Edition is that it is a standardised collection of those libraries, and a promise that they will all be available and will interoperate correctly.

Micro Edition is a cut-down version of the Standard Edition with a smaller class library and a much older version of the language (1.3, year 2000!). J2ME was designed to run on 2000-era mobile phones, many of which come with a JVM for it installed. I have no idea how you would actually deploy it on a server. Are there standalone J2ME runtime environments?

JavaFX is not an 'edition' of Java, it's a GUI library framework toolkit thing. You can safely ignore it.

Micro Edition is not a useful basis for developing server applications. The ancient version of the language and rudimentary libraries would make that a very painful task. There is no reason to think that it would be any faster than the Standard Edition.

The Standard Edition is a completely viable basis for developing server applications. People have been using it to do that for a long time. At my place of work, we have numerous servers which are developed using Standard Edition.

The Enterprise Edition is also a viable basis for developing server applications. However, it is heavily oriented towards a small number of protocols: primarily HTTP/HTTPS, RMI and IIOP, and messaging protocols. If you want to talk some other protocol, Enterprise Edition will be of rather little use. You may be better off taking the particular libraries that are useful to you, and using them in Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0):

For server applications I always use Java Standard Edition.  You can use Enterprise Edition as this is designed for faster time to market, esp for web applications, but if you need performance eg trading systems, it may not be fast enough, in which case you need to write more of the code yourself which means using the Java SE.

E.g. With Java SE you can build trading systems with latencies of 20 - 100 micro-seconds.  With Java EE  you will have a lot trouble finding latency number because they are more designed for throughput through horizontal scalability.

Comment: Any time you use even servlets you use Java EE.  Even if you run on the plain JVM - you just bring everything you need from Java EE yourself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Without a GUI you may not need servlets or anything in JEE to slow down your application. BTW My claim of little latency figures could be wrong, if you have see latency benchmarks for JEE, please correct me.

Comment: Perhaps we are confusing using Java EE _API_ s with using a Java EE _application server_?

Comment: (And I have made quite a few WAR files run on the plain JVM)

Comment: >` performance eg trading systems` - Perhaps the following links is interesting related to this: http://infoq.com/articles/low-latency-vp